# XmlObject [] to java.lang.Object[]

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have and XmlObject[] which has data something like : `list2` data

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:ax22="http://xyz...>
 <ax21:array>1</ax21:array>
 <ax21:array></ax21:array>
 <ax21:array>124029</ax21:array>
 <ax21:array>20170210</ax21:array>
 <ax21:array>2</ax21:array>
</xml-fragment>
 <xml-fragment>
 .....
```

Is there any easy way to convert it into `List<Objects[]>` or java `Array<A[]>` ? Please note that there are hundreds of such xml-fragment tags.

I am using Axis2 , with XML Binding as it supports java `Array`

Actually I recieve a `List<Object[]>` in webservices from group by clause in Hibernate using `query.list();` . Now in a webservice it must deals only with arrays no special `java.util.Collections` so i convert this `List<Object[]>` to an `Object[]` and send it as a response to the client in an `guiObject`.

Upon receiving response when I try to itertate over like : Client Code :

```
Object[] list2 = guiObject.getBatchListArray(); // This gives XmlObject[] which in turn contains other XmlAnyTypeImpl arrays.
for (Object entry : list2) { 
                Object[] obj = (Object[]) entry; // exception occurs here
```

it gives me Exception :

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

actual data contained by `guiObject` :

```
<xml-fragment xsi:type="ax21:GuiObject" xmlns:ax22="http://model.kgs.persistence/xsd" xmlns:ax21="http://model.kgs.ws/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://impl.kgs.ws" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ax21:accountNot xsi:nil="true"/>
  <ax21:assignedUser xsi:nil="true"/>
  <ax21:batchList>
    <ax21:array>1</ax21:array>
    <ax21:array>KOREFFAA</ax21:array>
    <ax21:array>103941</ax21:array>
    <ax21:array>20170201</ax21:array>
    <ax21:array>1</ax21:array>
  </ax21:batchList>
  <ax21:batchList>
.......
```

I am able to get data out of `guiObject` using getters but in case of arrays it is not possible. Help !

Comment: can you add some amount of Java code for others to understand what you have done so far and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with JAXB:

1) Create your POJO like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="xml-fragment")
public class Fragment {  
    @XmlAttribute(name="xmlns:ax22")
    private String ax22;
    @XmlElement(name="ax21")
    private String[] ax21;
    //getters, setters, constructor
}
```

2) Unmarshall your xml to object

```
   try {  

    File file = new File("xmlfile.xml");  
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Fragment.class);  

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
    Fragment frag= (Fragment) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  

    System.out.println(frag.getAX22());   

  } catch (JAXBException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
  }
```

Read more [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example).

Comment: it is giving null at frag.getAx21() and also at frag.getAx22(). why ?

Comment: it seems some problem is there when i use ax22 as with other names it is working fine. Any idea ?

Comment: If you are living problems with the values, you can try mappings with the annotations like I did at @XmlRootElement(name="xml-fragment") You can use tish for also @XmlAttribute(name="") and @XmlElement(name="")

Comment: well only with ax21 it is working but my data has <ax21:array> as a tag if I pass this as a name it is not working :( . See my question at beginning the list2 data .

Comment: Oh yes i got it now for <ax21:array> i must use @XmlRootElement(name="array"). Thanks for support @webmaster.

Comment: how to mark as correct ? I am not sure I voted your answer but my reputation is less and vote is recorded.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess the correct answer selection is available after some days, thanks any way